# gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/snappy/.node-gyp'

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS CodeBuild Project which tries to install serverless framework but returns an error in the title however it says framework successfully installed. My understanding is that this fails to install the snappy module. Why is that and how can I resolve this?

The command I run in my buildspec.yaml is:

```
npm install -g serverless
```

And my user is:

```
/root
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

in the first error line:

`gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody")...`

seems `node-gyp` is trying to use another user instead of `root`,

we can find the issue discussed in the package repository:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1236

the most recent solutions seems to be:

```
npm_config_user=root npm install -g ...
```

to force/set the environment user to be used by npm install process

Comment: Thanks @oieduardorabelo. I ended up using yarn which did not give me any errors. I will try to test this one too at some point.

Comment: For reproducible results, I advise against installing `serverless@latest` in your buildspec. By the way, some respondents in the node-gyp issue suggest adding `--unsafe` to the install command.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubanntu users

use

```
sudo npm i -g serverless
```